# Why doesnt the box shadow show above the footer div?

Tags: css

I have a box shadow on the #footermain div in the CSS, but I cant get it to show above the green footer.  Ive tried everything and I cant figure it out.

```
#footermain {
    background: #1f6c04;
    width: 100%;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 -5px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 -5px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    box-shadow: 0 -5px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}

#footerinner {
    height: 150px;
    width: 960px;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Here is my CSS for those that dont want to inspect the page

Comment: Add this to your `box-shadow` `0 5px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) inset`
Is this what you are looking for??

Comment: I want it to go above the footer, outside the box

Comment: @mishik thanks for the edit, I dont know why I struggle so bad with the formatting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give

```
position : relative;
```

to #footermain.

Comment: Genius!  Thank you Sir!  And yes, curious why this is as well.

Comment: Check this out : [http://jsfiddle.net/cemGk/](http://jsfiddle.net/cemGk/). By default second <div> is above first one. If first <div> has some position other than static, then it is above the second static <div>

Comment: Doesn't work if both are non-static - #footerinner lies above the shadow : (